# Python decorator for checking the return type: Especially check for nested things like List[List[List[str]]]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, python-typing

I'm trying to write my one python decorator for type checking. It works well, but struggles with nested type hints. For example take

```py
@type_check
def fun(x: int) -> List[List[List[str]]]:
    return [[[str(x)]]]

fun(x=42)
```

I have a decorator, which eveluates the function and checks, if the actual return value has the expected type:

```py
import inspect
# inside the decorator
actual_result = func(*args, **kwargs)              # [[['42']]]
expected_result_type = spec.annotations['return']  # typing.List[typing.List[typing.List[str]]]
```

And now is challenge to check is `[[['42']]]` has type `typing.List[typing.List[typing.List[str]]]`.
How can I do that?

All I found out, is that `[[['42']]]` has simply type `<class 'list'>` which ignores the information about nesting completly.
And I can check this with

```py
if hasattr(expected_result_type, '__origin__'):
    expected_result_type = expected_result_type.__origin__

if expected_result_type is not None:
    assert isinstance(result, expected_result_type)
else: # None is kind of a special case
    assert result is expected_result_type
```

This works on the "outer layer", but ignores nested type hints. Is there any way to check all layers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer would be:

Simply recurse into all arguments like:

```py
def type_check(value, annotation):
    if isinstance(annotation, type):
        return isinstance(value, annotation)
    elif annotation == typing.T or annotation == typing.Any:
        return True
    elif isinstance(annotation, typing._GenericAlias):
        if annotation.__origin__ == list:
            if not isinstance(value, list):
                return False
            inner_annotation = annotation.__args__[0]
            return all(type_check(val, inner_annotation) for val in value)
```

Example

```py
>>> type_check(5, int)
True
>>> type_check([1, 2, 3], typing.List[int])
True
>>> type_check([1, 2, 3], typing.List[float])
False
```

Which you can simply use in you decorator. It might be improved to handle Dict, Tuple and other common types.

However it's just a toy example, if you want to do robust dynamic type checking, you'll have to handle `Generator`, `Callable`, `Iterator` etc... which is not only quite complex but also in some case completely impossible (Iterators for example can't be checked unless iterated over).

Have a look at the [enforce project](https://github.com/RussBaz/enforce) which is exactly that: a python dynamic type checking using decorators. The `typing` module source code is also really interesting to read, but really pushes the limits of what dynamic introspection can do.

Hope it helps ;)